# Would storing logical volumes on a ZFS storage benefit from caching?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, zfs, iscsi

What I'm planning to do is having a ZFS storage connected to my network. Attaching it with either iSCSI or SRP to the hypervisor server. And storing KVM images (logical volumes) on it.

Would this setup benefit from ZFS's caching in the memory?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using ZFS storage as a backing for a virtual environment takes advantages of the filesystem's efficiencies.

Design will matter quite a bit, as you'll want a proper dedicated ZIL write cache device to handle bursts of random write activity. The L2ARC caching will serve as a large SSD-based read-cache.

But even without dedicated ZIL/L2ARC devices, the storage server can make efficient use of the RAM and CPU inside the system. 32GB RAM or more is recommended...

Another consideration is the value of compression in ZFS. I enable compression for most installations and there's a good performance and efficiency benefit.

An example from my ZFS storage array for VMware...

*Read cache hit-ratio is nearly 80%*
[image]

Comment: I was just asking about the RAM caching actually since I don't plan to use ZIL or L2ARC devices. It should still do RAM caching without those devices, right?

Comment: @ispirto *But even without dedicated ZIL/L2ARC devices, the storage server can make efficient use of the RAM and CPU inside the system. 32GB RAM or more is recommended...*

Comment: A bit offtopic, however regarding the CPU, what would you recommend? Would having dual quad core make a much difference than having a single quad core?

Comment: @ispirto Only if you enable compression (which you should). I'd say the minimum CPU would be something like an Intel E5620. I run single and dual CPU's in my ZFS installations. Dual X5680's or X5690's for bigger installations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. zVol can use both ARC/L2Arc and ZIL if those are configured. The defaults are to use them.

Comment: Careful. The default on illumos-derivatives utilizing COMSTAR (most of them) is actually usually to NOT use the ZIL for normal iSCSI traffic. You need to be sure 'writeback cache' is NOT enabled on the LU, or most setups will end up completely skipping ZIL mechanics.